# chrome extension content.js file loads too early: unable to find an element in DOM

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to add a listener to the linkedIn 'create post' button through a chrome extension

**Now, because I added a timeout, the button is found, but if I run it directly or with a smaller timeout (eg 1000ms) the button is not found**

Here's my code:

```js
function findStartPostField() {
  const lnCssSelector = '.share-box-feed-entry__trigger'
  let button = document.querySelector(lnCssSelector)
  console.log('button found ', button)
  if (button)
    button.addEventListener('click', () => alert('clicked'))
}

setTimeout(findStartPostField, 5000)

console.log('content js loaded, registering message listener');
```

In my manifest, I tried `run_at` with document_end and document_idle values without success.

I don't like the idea of having to put a timeout. Is there an event like 'onload' that would trigger when all JS has finished executing (somehow saying the document is rendered and ready)

Comment: You can use event delegation i.e. register a click listener on document.body and check event.target inside. An alternative is `MutationObserver`.

Comment: Thank you @wOxxOm I'll try that monday, inshallah, and get back to you

Comment: Does work @wOxxOm, thank you. But seems not ideal for performance, as my code will intercept each click

Comment: It depends on how often the user clicks in that page. If it's 1000 times per second then indeed it's bad for performance.

Comment: Lol, you're right!

Seen from this perspective, that totally makes sense. But still felling like, hopefully not every extension developer will think that way (having 30 extensions processing on each click) :-)

Do you want to answer, so I can select your answer as the correct one?

Comment: Add `"run_at": "document_end"` in "content_scripts" `in manifest.json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an implementation based on wOxxOm's comment.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.className == 'share-box-feed-entry__trigger') {
    alert('clicked');
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you @Norio for translating wOxxOm's thoughts into code :-), I'll check if that works and reach back to you

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. Using `message passing`.

1. Firstly register a `onload` event listener on the extension client side.
2. Inside the extension's client side onload event listener, send `one time message` to the content-script.
3. On the content-script side, for catching incoming messages, register `chrome.runtime.onMessage` event listener and read the onload type message sent from extension side. Here you can do your DOM mutation.

For example -

#### popup.js

```
addEventListener("load", (event) => {
    chrome?.tabs?.sendMessage({
        type: 'ONDOMLOADED',
        sender: 'EXTENSION'
    }, function(response) {
       console.log(response);
    });
});
```

#### content_script.js

```
chrome?.runtime?.onMessage?.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse)  {
    const type = request?.type;
    console.assert(request?.sender === 'EXTENSION');
    switch(type) {
       case 'ONDOMLOADED': {
           // DOM ALL THE onDOM CONTENT LODADED THINGS HERE
           findStartPostField();
           return sendResponse({
               type: 'ONDOMLOADED_RESPONSE'
           });
       }
       default:
           return;
    }     
});
```

### 2. Using `window.onload`

#### content_script.js

```
window?.onload = function () {
    findStartPostField()
}
```

Hope, it helps you :)

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your answer, since I said in the question that the document is still not ready when the 'load' event is triggered. Meaning, the DOM is not yet constructed at that time, that's why I'm adding a timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation using `MutationObserver`.

```js
const onMutation = (mutations) => {
  mo.disconnect();
  for (const { addedNodes } of mutations) {
    for (const node of addedNodes) {
      if (node) {
        if (node.className) {
          if (node.className == 'share-box-feed-entry__trigger') {
            node.addEventListener('click', () => alert('clicked'))
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  observe();
}

const observe = () => {
  mo.observe(document, {
    subtree: true,
    childList: true,
  });
}

const mo = new MutationObserver(onMutation);

observe();
```